# SQL: Comparing count of 2 fields with specific value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one (Jobs) contains the list of the jobs and second contains the details of the records in each job.

```
Jobs            
JobID   Count       
A       2       
B       3       


Records         
JobID   RecordID    ToBeProcessed   IsProcessed
A           A1          1           1
A           A2          1           1
B           B1          1           1
B           B2          1           0
B           B3          1           0
```

How would I be able to create a query that would list all the jobs that have the count of ToBeProcessed which has a value of 1 is equal to the count of isProcessed that has a value of 1? Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework. Have you tried solving it?

Comment: Yes, but I am stuck in trying to compare the count of 2 fields.

Comment: You should post your best non-working attempt then - you are probably very close, just need one small final push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the calculation of the number of items with `ToBeProcessed` set to `1` or `IsProcessed` set to one:

```
SELECT
    JobID
,   SUM(CASE WHEN ToBeProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ToBeProcessedIsOne
,   SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsProcessedIsOne
FROM Records
GROUP BY JobID
```

This gives you all counts, not only ones where `ToBeProcessedIsOne` is equal to `IsProcessedIsOne`. To make sure that you get only the records where the two are the same, use either a `HAVING` clause, or a nested subquery:

```
-- HAVING clause
SELECT
    JobID
,   SUM(CASE WHEN ToBeProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ToBeProcessedIsOne
,   SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsProcessedIsOne
FROM Records
GROUP BY JobID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ToBeProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

-- Nested subquery with a condition
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        JobID
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ToBeProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ToBeProcessedIsOne
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsProcessedIsOne
    FROM Records
    GROUP BY JobID
) WHERE ToBeProcessedIsOne = IsProcessedIsOne
```

Note: if `ToBeProcessed` and `IsProcessed` are of type that does not allow values other than zero or one, you can replace the `CASE` statement with the name of the column, for example:

```
SELECT
    JobID
,   SUM(ToBeProcessed) ToBeProcessedIsOne
,   SUM(IsProcessed) IsProcessedIsOne
FROM Records
GROUP BY JobID
HAVING SUM(ToBeProcessed)=SUM(IsProcessedD)
```

Comment: @VigneshKumar If `ToBeProcessed` or `IsProcessed` could have other values, say, `-1` or `2`, then a `CASE` is needed. If these columns are of type `bit`, case is unnecessary.

Comment: What I was trying to do is the exist in where clause and check if the count of the 2 fields are the same.


SELECT * 
FROM   jobs 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   records 
               WHERE  jobs.jobid = records.jobid 
               HAVING Count(records.tobeprocessed) = Count(records.isprocessed)) 

But the result is not OK. :(

Comment: Would it be possible to use the main query in jobs table and subquery for the checking of the counts?

Comment: @JohnGo You could join the results of this query to the `jobs` table if you wish, for example, to bring any additional fields: `SELECT * FROM jobs j JOIN (SELECT ... HAVING ...) sub ON j.JobID=sub.JobID`

Answer (score 0):

if im not misunderstanding your question it looks like you just need a WHERE clause in your statement to see when they are both equal to 1.

```
 SELECT
      r.JobID AS j_id,
      r.RecordID as r_id,
      r.ToBeProcessed AS tbp,
      r.IsProcessed AS ip
 FROM Records AS r
 WHERE r.ToBeProcessed = 1 AND r.IsProcessed = 1
 GROUP BY j_id;
```

let me know if this is not what you are asking for.

---

if its a count from a different table then just do a count of the tbp and ip rows grouped by jobID and then the where should still do the trick